# Select box laravel undefined variable

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

My select box isn´t working. Trying to display on the select option the names of the table (departments) in a view. The error I get it is :

**Undefined variable: department (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\views\users\form.blade.php)**

This is my controller

```
    public function edit($userID)
    {
        $usuario = User::query()->findOrFail($userID);
        $roles = Role::pluck('display_name','id');
        $departments = Department::all();

        return view('users.edit',compact('usuario','roles','departments'));
    }
```

and my view

```
      <select name="department_id" id="department_id" class="form-select">
          {{--@foreach($departments as $department)--}}
                <option value="{{$department->id}}">{{$department->name}}</option>
          {{--@endforeach--}}
      </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="department_id" id="department_id" class="form-select">
   @foreach ($departments as $department)
       <option value="{{$department->id}}">{{$department->name}}
   @endforeach
</option>
```

Looping on the blade is look like this

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel Blade the syntax `{{--` means that the following is commented out. In your case you commented out the iteration of your departments collection. And that the reason why $department is undefined.

Instead of `{{--@foreach($departments as $department)--}}` you have to use `@foreach($departments as $department)` ... `@endforeach`

Answer (score 0):

I solve it changing the controller and without the comments

```
   public function edit($userID)
    {
        $usuario = User::query()->findOrFail($userID);
        $roles = Role::pluck('display_name','id');
        $departments = Department::all(['id','name']);
        //dd($departments);
        return view('users.edit',compact('usuario','roles','departments'));
    }
```

```
<select name="department_id" id="department_id" class="form-select">
        @foreach ($departments as $department)
            <option value="{{$department->id}}">{{$department->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
```